# Material UI scrollable tabs not rendering in Internet Explorer

Tags: javascript, reactjs, material-ui

I am in the process of implementing Material UI for our tab control in our React Web UI. This has worked fine within Chrome, but the second we have tried testing this within IE, the page refuses to load and the console throws the following error:

> Unhandled promise rejection Invariant Violation: Maximum update depth exceeded. This can happen when a component repeatedly calls setState inside componentWillUpdate or componentDidUpdate. React limits the number of nested updates to prevent infinite loops.

Below is the code that has been added around Material-UI. As mentioned, this works fine in Chrome, but just appears to fall over within IE. The specific line that breaks IE is the `scrollable={true}` line - if this is removed or changed to false, the page will render (albeit without the scrolling we require). Not sure if there are any particular gotchas we need to watch out for in IE with regards to Material-UI?

```
    var menuString = isList ? null : <AppBar position="static" color="default"><Tabs
        scrollable={true}
        value={activeItem}
        onChange={this.handleTabSelection}
        scrollButtons="auto"
        classes={{ indicator: "tabsIndicator" }}>
        {
            jsxData.map((item, index) => {
                return (
                    <Tab key={index} value={item.name} label={item.name} 
                    classes={{ selected: "tabSelected" }}/>
                );
            })
        }
    </Tabs></AppBar>;

    return <Segment basic className={"report-group-render " + (isList ? "list" : "tabs")}>
        {menuString}
    </Segment>;
```

Answer (score 0):

The answer was that `jsxData.map(...)` returns an empty array for a few iterations before finally being rendered with its array of reports. Chrome ignores/swallows these initial empty-array issues without raising concern, where as IE decides to break itself.

The solution was to change the first line to the following:

```
var menuString = isList || jsxData.length === 0 ? null : <AppBar position="static" color="default"><Tabs
```